# how to change bootstrap panel height's to equal the body height's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

trying to change `bootstrap` `panel` `height`'s to be `equal` the `body` `height`'s

so to be like side bar :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary ">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome User!</div>
                <div class="panel-body client-left-side">
                    Cpanel Menu
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">Logout Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

result :

[image]

I want to stretch it , so it's `height` from the end of the `navigation bar`till the beginning of the `footer`...

EDIT:  [link to the test page](http://abanoub.me/bebrand/test)

Answer (score 3):

I like this, personally:

```
.panel-primary {
    height: calc(100vh - 145px);
}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Two points

**1)** Bootstrap-3 doesnot let you play with `height` easily. If you want to play with height then you have to go for `table` structure where you can set the `row-span` of each `column`s, BUT this is NOT a good approach.

**2)** The other way (easy) is that to use jquery for this. All you need to do is to get the `height` of `#body` and set the `height` of `panel` to `#body`'s `height`. You might some media queries here too.

Comment: I have tried that I didn't work correctly!  
`.........

<div id="left-side" class="panel-body client-left-side">
...........

 <script>
  $("#left-side").height($("body").height());
 </script>`

Comment: Give some `setTimeout` -> 5 sec to this. Because may be DOM is not fully prepared when it called !!

Comment: `window` and `document` is not fitting well , I think I have to subtract the `top-nav` height's and the `footer-nav` from the `document` height's , but isn't there a better way to do that?!

Comment: Yeah that would be better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the heights to 100% you should give your enclosing div's the proper height as well. I am guessing your col,row and container are not the full height till the footer.

If you could provide the URL, its easier to see and provide you with a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to increase the `panel-body` height, not the entire `panel`. One way to do this is to use CSS flexbox and make sure any of the panels containers are 100% height (including the html and body)

http://www.bootply.com/BZQYq01ABC